Dropbox list_folder limit does not work as expected
I have a curl call curl -X POST https://api.dropboxapi.com/2/files/list_folder 
--header 'Authorization: Bearer {{ACCESS_TOKEN}}' 
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' 
--data '{"path":"/Apps","recursive":true,"limit":10,"include_non_downloadable_files":true,"include_mounted_folders":true}'
I expect total of 10 entries returned recursively, I have nested folders. However I am getting 3 entries. I have about 30 files in dropbox, I need to paginate 10 at a time.
As per the documentation https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-list_folder
limit UInt32(min=1, max=2000)?The maximum number of results to return per request. Note: This is an approximate number and there can be slightly more entries returned in some cases. This field is optional.
Limit should work. Anyone experienced this issue?

The page size returned by /2/files/list_folder or /2/files/list_folder/continue is not guaranteed, and the 'limit' parameter is the "maximum number of results to return per request". As that is only a maximum, the server will attempt to not return more than that per page, but it is not guaranteed to return that amount per page, and may return less than that amount.
Regardless of the number of returned entries on any given page and also regardless of the specified 'limit' value, the app should always check the returned 'has_more' value to determine if it should call back to /2/files/list_folder/continue to get more results. Please refer to the documentation linked above for information on using that.
